# Can I use Windows Fax and Scan with a ScanSnap scanner?

Tags: windows-10, scanner

The Fujitsu / PFU Limited ScanSnap manager software is... not my favorite. I'd like to try the built-in Windows Fax and Scan application instead. But, when I click "New Scan", I get this error:

> No scanners were detected. If a scanner is installed, make sure that it is powered on and connected to the computer, and then try again.
>   For information about adding or troubleshooting scanners, see Help and Support

The scanner is powered on, the "device" is detected, and drivers are installed/updated.

[image]

*Screenshot of Device Manager*

The Fax and Scan application is still included in Windows 10, so I assume it's supported? But, I can't find a list of supported devices or, really, any recent documentation.

Comment: The `Fax and Scan` application does indeed still work.

Comment: Are you using the latest (Windows 10) driver/software from Fujitsu?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I have not installed anything directly from Fujitsu. I let Windows 10 detect the device and install whatever drivers it knows about.

Comment: Then you should  try that.  Head to Fujitsu's site and try the latest driver they offer for you scanner/OS.

Comment: Fujitsu does not have a separate downloadable "driver". They have their ScanSnap manager software, which I said I was not interested in using (having used it for many years, I'm curious if I can use the built-in Fax and Scan application).

Comment: The driver is installed and up-to-date, according to the Device Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old post but it seems like ScanSnap scanners do not support TWAIN or WIA drivers. These kind of drivers enable the scanners to be used by 3rd party applications (In this case non-fujitsu applications). The WIA is the driver you need for the Windows Fax & Scan to be able to see a scanner, but ScanSnap seems to not support that. So I think we are out of luck here.

Basically, it seems like fujitsu has locked their ScanSnap products to only work with their software. Look at the 2nd answer here:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/fujitsu-ix500-neeed-wia-driver-to-use/704d680b-a866-4eed-9811-b166145a6bb0

You can check if this is your issue if you go to Control Panel>Devices and Printer, and right click on the scanner > Start Scan. If it tells you you need a WIA driver then this applies to your scenario.

Comment: They recently released a new "universal" scansnap manager and that one doesn't even connect to this device :(

Answer (score -1):

In ScanSnap set your Output to Print instead of a file and then choose Fax as your printer.

Comment: OP isn't asking how to fax from Scan Snap. They're asking how to use the Fax and Scan utility to do their scanning.

Comment: The OP, Anthony Mastrean, wants to try Windows Fax and Scan INSTEAD of Fujitsu.  I had the same question and obviously, you can't.  

I came here because I was trying to FAX as the purpose for scanning, since it's part of the title of the application.  For anybody else trying to Fax using ScanSnap you have to use the Fax and Scan utility.